# Fit the content of container

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to force inner element (div.-not-assignable-) to fit the whole content of div.item-wrapper. The style -not-assignable- can't be defined/changed (if there is no solution will use React.clone to assign a proper style in order to solve the issue - just curious about a pure CSS solution).

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  height: 50px;
}

.item-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-wrapper">
    <div style="border: 1px solid red;" class="-not-assignable-">Div</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display:grid` instead of flex will do it because you will have the stretch effect on both sides:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  height: 50px;
}

.item-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  min-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-wrapper">
    <div style="border: 1px solid red;" class="-not-assignable-">Div</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could select `-not-assignable-` via `.item-wrapper > div` and use the rule `flex-grow:1;`:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  height: 50px;
}

.item-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.item-wrapper>div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-wrapper">
    <div style="border: 1px solid red;" class="-not-assignable-">Div</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can remove display flex from the .item-wrapper

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  
}

.item-wrapper {
  min-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-wrapper">
    <div style="border: 1px solid red;" class="-not-assignable-">Div</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. Used height: 50px on purpose - would like that inner div fits both the width and the height of the wrapper.

Comment: @DraganS you can use height on the inner div only.
Note: don't use height in container class of bootstrap. it will effect on all container of the page